# Are all the zeros of $1-a_2x^2+a_4x^4-a_6x^6+\cdots$ real for $a_{2n}>a_{2(n+1)}$ with $a_{2n+1}=0$ and $a_{2n}>0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, roots

This question is related to a [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864448/power-series-with-alternating-signs-and-its-zeros) question of mine. 
I was not pleased about the conditions I provided there. I had something different in mind but I failed in stating it. So here are the premises. Supose I have a power series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}x^{k}$ and:

1. $a_{0}=1$;
2. $a_{2n+1}=0$;
3. $a_{2n}>a_{2(n+1)}$;
4. $a_{2n}>0$.

My questions:

1. Does this kind of power series allways have real zeros?
2. If not are there counterexamples?

I've made some quick checking for $\cos(x)$, shifting the value of $a_{2n}$, and it seems that all the roots remain real provided that we obey the above conditions nevertheless the number of roots changes from infinite to finite.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The same objection as before](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864488/44121) holds. If we consider
$$ f(z)=1-a_2 z+a_4 z^2-a_6 z^3 +\ldots $$
the fact that $\{a_{2n}\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a positive decreasing sequence do not give that Newton's inequalities are fulfilled. If [Newton's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_inequalities) are not fulfilled, $f(z)$ cannot have only real roots and the same applies to your original function. For instance, the disciminant of the third-degree polynomial
$$ p(z) = 1-\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{4}-\frac{z^3}{8} $$
is negative, hence $p(z)$ has some complex root and the sequence $a_2=\frac{1}{2},a_4=\frac{1}{4},a_6=\frac{1}{8},$ $a_8=\varepsilon,a_{10}=\frac{\varepsilon}{2},a_{12}=\frac{\varepsilon}{4},\ldots$ gives a counter-example for any sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$.

---

The only question that makes sense is the following:

> If $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a real sequence fulfilling Newton's inequalities and 
>   $$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n $$ is an analytic/entire function, can we say that all the roots of $f$ are real?

Unluckily, the answer is negative also in that case, always by a perturbation argument: it is enough to consider $f(x)=\varepsilon+e^{-x}$ for some small $\varepsilon>0$. So Newton's inequalities can be used to prove the existence of some complex root, but not to prove that every root is real.

At some meta-level, [theorems ensuring that every root of something is real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) have to be fairly complex (pun intended). Otherwise, RH would have been solved centuries ago.

Comment: Note that $a_{2n}\in\left ]0,1\right] $ and that $a_0=1$.

Comment: @Neves: irrelevant, but fixed.

Comment: How does the polynomial $p(z)$ relates to the power series $f(z)$?

Comment: A polynomial is a power series. We are taking $f(z)$ as the sum of a polynomial and $\varepsilon$ times an analytic function. If $\epsilon$ is small enough and $p(z)$ has a complex root, $f(z)$ has a complex root, too.

Comment: But, $a_{2n+1}=0$

Comment: @Neves: yes, in the first sequence giving the counter-example we have $a_{2n+1}=0$. I think it is easier this way - what is not clear in my answer, in your opinion? You do not seem to have grasped the central fact: if you set some constraints that allow a sequence to violate Newton's inequality, the associated analytic function may still have a complex  root. Now, your constraints on $\{a_{2n}\}$ to be positive, decreasing, in $[0,1]$ etc... are kind of irrelevant, since they allow a violation of Newton's inequalities, so they cannot ensure that all the roots are real.

Comment: The only relevant constraint is to start with a sequence that fulfills Newton's inequalities, but also that relevant constraint turns out to be inconclusive about the localization of zeroes, as shown in the second part of my answer.